# Two column width 50% css

Tags: html, css

I want to make a two column layout using DIVs, where right column will have 50% width and the left one would take 50% too.
How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything mate?

Comment: he tried asking on SO!

Comment: This: http://jsfiddle.net/59W94/, also CSS columns, CSS tables...there are a lot of ways - but you may want to demonstrate what you've attempted, what you require what has worked and what hasnt.

Comment: What are you willing to use? Are you willing to use (CSS) Frameworks? Do you want it in pure HTML/CSS? 
Show us you put effort in it before asking this question, otherwise I don't think you'll receive much help...

Comment: I will keep in mind & ask better questions later. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/9MVLc/)**

html

```
<div class="div1">Left div</div>
<div class="div2">Right div</div>
```

css

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.div1 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 100%;
}
.div2 {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    background: #aaa;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a large number of ways, without knowing what you've attempted, what your requirements are, what will work for you and what wont its a bit of a shot in the dark - but I'll give you a high level example of a number of techniques.

1. Use inline elements with 50% width, they will next against one another horizontally
2. Float two elements with width 50%, they will nest horizontally
3. Use CSS3 columns
4. Use CSS tables with two table cells, one for each column

I would tend to recommend using the CSS column approach if supported, as it is specifically designed for the purpose...that said, its hard to know what the precise purpose at hand is.

### [Examples](http://jsfiddle.net/59W94/1/)

HTML

```
<h1>Inline</h1>

<div class='inline'></div>
<div class='inline'></div>

<h1>Float</h1>

<div class='float'></div>
<div class='float'></div>

<h1>Columns</h1>

<div class='cols'>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>

<h1>Table</h1>

<div class='table'>
    <div class='cell'></div>
    <div class='cell'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    font-size:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
h1 {
    font-size:20px;
}
div {
    border:1px solid;
    height:200px;
    width:50%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-size:14px;
}
.inline {
    display:inline-block;
}
.float {
    float:left;
}
.cols {
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    width:100%;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
}
```