# Edit the distance between two inline elements

Tags: html, css

At present I have 2 columns of content displaying inline on the same line.

The next challenge I am trying to overcome is getting these two elements to be closer together on that same line.

I think I may have found the answer here, but not really sure what it means. If this is the correct way of achieving said outcome, an explanation of the contents would be very helpful: [Two column width 50% css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134502/two-column-width-50-css)

Alternatively, I have the current CSS set up on my stylesheet:

```css
.fields-1 {
 float: left;
 width: 46%;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto auto auto 0;
}

.fields-2 {
 float: right;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline;
 width: 46%;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-left: -15px;
 margin: auto 0 auto auto;
}

.fields-2 p {
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: 500px;
}

#disclaimer {
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 17px;
 font-family: calibri;
 font-style: strong;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 width: 45%;
}

#your-name {
 width: 45%;
 margin-right: 2px;
}

#your-email {
 width: 45%;
 margin-right: 2px;
}

#NewsletterOptions {
 width: 45%;
 height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fields-1">
<p style="text-align: center">[text* your-name id:your-name placeholder: "Team Name/Filmmaker"] <b>(required)</b></p>

<p style="text-align: center">[email* your-email id:your-email placeholder: "Email Address"] <b>(required)</b></p>
<p id="disclaimer">*Your e-mail helps us discuss your contribution with you; this email will not be used for any third party or internal promotions without consent.</p>
</div>
<div class="fields-2">
<p>Would you like 3 new short films to watch each month? </p> <br>
[select* NewsletterOptions id:NewsletterOptions "Yes sure, sounds good!" "Not at the moment, thank you." "Already signed up."]

</div>
```

Just for context it is 1 half of a contact form.

**Any feedback or information, you can provide on this matter would be much appreciated.**

Also, if you cold suggest a way for me to line up the Disclaimer text at the bottom with the other elements in that first '.div' I would be most grateful.

Kind regards,

Dan

Comment: You can't use `display:inline` and `float` at the same time...pick one or the other. If you want them to be closer together change the widths to closer to 50% each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a wrapper around the two divs and use flexbox, which will give you a column-like distribution of the two divs next to each other:

```
.wrapper {
      display: flex; 
      justify content: space-around;
}
```

In the snippet below I erased some superfluous stuff - not sure what you'd want to keep and what not.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex; 
  justify content: center;
 }
.fields-1 {
 width: 46%;
 text-align: center;
}

.fields-2 {
 text-align: center;
 width: 46%;
 padding-top: 5px;
}

.fields-2 p {
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: 500px;
}

#disclaimer {
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 17px;
 font-family: calibri;
 font-style: strong;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#your-name {
 margin-right: 2px;
}

#your-email {
 margin-right: 2px;
}

#NewsletterOptions {
 width: 45%;
 height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="fields-1">
<p style="text-align: center">[text* your-name id:your-name placeholder: "Team Name/Filmmaker"] <b>(required)</b></p>

<p style="text-align: center">[email* your-email id:your-email placeholder: "Email Address"] <b>(required)</b></p>
<p id="disclaimer">*Your e-mail helps us discuss your contribution with you; this email will not be used for any third party or internal promotions without consent.</p>
</div>
<div class="fields-2">
<p>Would you like 3 new short films to watch each month? </p> <br>
[select* NewsletterOptions id:NewsletterOptions "Yes sure, sounds good!" "Not at the moment, thank you." "Already signed up."]

</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your speedy response. I have added your code over mine. However the result is the same.

Comment: What should I add to the flex box now to bring the 2 columns closer together?

Comment: You can do different things: Try `justify-content: center` on the wrapper, which moves them together in the horizontal middle of the container. If that's too close, use margins left/right. Also try to change the width settings for left and right DIV. And remove that negative `padding-left` on the right container (  I forgot that in my snippet, bu I changed it now, and also changed `justify-content: center`)

Comment: Thank you for that.

I should have run the snippet first. Realised what you did now,

Comment: What does the space between one do? I have tried center but it didnt seem to make any difference between that and space around.

Comment: `space between` distributes the flex items evenly in a way that the outer ones (which in your case are the only two...) are aligned to the margins of the parent container. `space-around` would distribute the empty space between the child containers *and* the margins evenly (leaving some space at the sides), and `center` puts everything in the middle without space between the child containers (= only space at the sides).

Comment: Nice one, I have managed to get it looking good on desktop, but it is too small and squished on mobile device. How can I make the field fall under one another if the screen size narrows? Thank you for all your help so far.

Comment: with a media query where you add `flex-direction: column;` to the wrapper. Hey, at least you could mark my answer as helpful...

Comment: AHHH Sorry, I am still getting used to the Stack Exchange system. I have ticked it now, thank you so much for your help. The page looks great now!